# <div> Element Footer White Background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm new to web development (and JS and Jquery) and I have a question that I can't find. I've created a footer so that I can link to the platform where you want to download your game on. I've hit a snag - the `<div>` element of my footer is white, but I want it transparent.

Here's my code:

CSS:

```
body {
    background: url(images/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1280px 913px;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

li {
display:inline;
}

.footer
{
margin-top: 752px;
margin-left: 110.00000001px;
padding:0;
background-color:none;
}

.links
{
margin: 24px;
padding: -40px;
border: 0;
}

/*inline = horizontal nav menu; block = vertical nav bar*/
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<html>

<head>
<title>Sonic the Hedgehog 4: Episode 1</title> 
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/page1.css"> 
</head>

<body> 

<audio autoplay>
<source src="music/splashhillzone.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>


<div class="container-fluid">
<li><a href="page1.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="page2.html">Story</a></li>
<li><a href="page3.html">Zones</a></li>
<li><a href="page4.html">Badniks</a></li> 
<li><a href="page5.html">Media</a></li>
</ul> 
</div> 

<div class="footer">
<div class="panel-footer">
<a target="_blank" class="links" href="https://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/HzlsX88COYTMDJaVQYE3M9Yww89OErL5" style="text-align:center"><img src="CSS/images/wiiware.png" width="160" height="120"></a>

<a target="_blank" class="links" href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sega.sonic4epi" style="text-align:center"><img src="CSS/images/googleplay.png" width="160" height="120"></a>

<a target="_blank" class="links" href="http://store.steampowered.com/app/202530/"><img src="CSS/images/steam.png" width="160" height="120" style="text-align:center"></a>

<a target="_blank" class="links" href="http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/SONIC-4-Episode-I/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d80258410a07" style="text-align:center"><img src="CSS/images/xbox.jpg" width="160" height="120"></a> 
</div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Since I want to practice JS and Jquery, I preferably want the answer in either of the two languages.

I searched before hand but I can't find my answer.

EDIT: Here's my page. NOTE: I did not adapt my page to be viewed for fullscreens (F11) so ignore it.

[http://i.imgur.com/5L7XLTW.png](https://i.imgur.com/5L7XLTW.png)

Comment: Please post the relevant code _within_ your question. Create a [MCVE] so we can see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Simple CSS:

```
background-color: transparent;
```

In the future, when posting Web Development questions, it's expected to use a `"code pen"` like site that allows easy visualization and creation of small workable examples, with `CSS, HTML and javascript` all self-contained.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to make the background color transparent, you need to add the following CSS rule to `.footer` class:

```
background-color: transparent;
```

This will make the background transparent

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. worked for me .

```
.footer {
background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the background colour using rgb with complete opacity?

```
background-color:rgb(255,0,0,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some Minor Errors:


1.You need to add an open `<ul>` tag in `<div class="container-fluid">` as described below:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="page1.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page2.html">Story</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page3.html">Zones</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page4.html">Badniks</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page5.html">Media</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

2. Secondly for your goal of `footer` class to be transparent add this code piece into your CSS:

```css
.footer {
  margin-top: 752px;
  margin-left: 110.00000001px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

You can also view your code live at : https://plnkr.co/edit/gG8HbutEKkWbpAWSW3nC

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the browser's DOM inspection tools, you will see that the Bootstrap CSS contains `background-color: #f5f5f5;` for the `panel-footer` class.

So the solution is to set `background-color: transparent` in your own CSS.

The other answers have this too, but they all neglect to mention that it is the `panel-footer` class you need to apply this to, rather than the `footer` class.

```css
.panel-footer {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```